# How to support serving a blob using range request?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am serving PDFs from the blobstore.  I would now like to add support for range request.  I am at a point where I can obtain the appropriate byte range and I am trying to pass the range to GAE as described in the link below and shown below.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Serving_a_blob

resp.setHeader("X-AppEngine-BlobRange", range); //where range might equal "0-5"
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);

It appears that no matter the range requested the response is 416 - Requested Range Not Satisfiable.  I have tested this manually with multiple different ranges and it doesn't matter what the values are the range does not work.  This is consistent for both the dev server and when deployed.  Am I missing something that is causing this error?  Is there any reason why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding res.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes"); appears to have fixed this.